# MVC Core Entity Framework Core returns rows but no data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

Im trying to create a drop down bow in MVC but it doesn't seem to populate any data into it. the database table has thousands of rows but i can't seem to get it to display any of it.

**Model**

```
    public class FlSessions
{
    public FlSessions()
    {
        FlBookings = new HashSet<FlBookings>();
    }

    public int FsId { get; set; }
    public int? FsOldid { get; set; }
    public string FsAyrc { get; set; }
    public string FsCentre { get; set; }
    public string FsType { get; set; }
    public DateTime? FsDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? FsStart { get; set; }
    public DateTime? FsEnd { get; set; }
    public decimal? FsDuration { get; set; }
    public int? FsPlaces { get; set; }
    public string FsNotes { get; set; }
    public string FsDead { get; set; }
    public string FsCreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? FsCreated { get; set; }
    public string FsSessionText { get; set; }
    public virtual FlCentres FsCentreNavigation { get; set; }
    public virtual FlSessionTypes FsTypeNavigation { get; set; }
    public ICollection<FlBookings> FlBookings { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
    public class BookingController : Controller
{
    public FlexibleLearningTestContext _context;
    public BookingController(FlexibleLearningTestContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    public IActionResult IndexTest()
    {
        ViewBag.sessions = _context.FlSessions.ToList();
        return View();
    }
}
```

**View**

```
 @{
 Layout = "_Layout";
 }
 <form>
 <label asp-for="FsSessionText"></label>
 <select id="SelectedSession1" name="FsId1" asp-for="FsSessionText" asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.sessions,"FsId","FsSessionText" ))">
    <option>Select Session...</option>
 </select>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not best pratice
if you want best practice create a view model that contains List
then fill it in controller then pass it to view and just use asp-items.

Try to use this

```
ViewBag.sessions=_context.FlSessions.Select(c => new SelectListItem()
          {
              Text = c.FsSessionText,
              Value = c.FsId.ToString(),
          }).ToList();
```

then in view just write below code

```
<select id="SelectedSession1" name="FsId1" asp-for="FsSessionText" asp-items="@ViewBag.sessions">
```

Comment: "Id" and "name" with the asp-for helper are not necessary

Comment: İts true if you used asp-for there is no need name and id tag